# Delay in google vision callback

Tags: android, google-vision

I am using `Google Vision Api` for face detection. I want to enable capture button when the face is detected in the camera otherwise disable. Its working fine, only the issue is when there is a face button is enabled, but on face not available, button disables after 1/1.5 seconds because `onDone` callback of `Tracker` is called after 1, or 1.5 seconds.

```
private class GraphicFaceTracker extends Tracker<Face> {
        private GraphicOverlay mOverlay;
        private FaceGraphic mFaceGraphic;

        GraphicFaceTracker(GraphicOverlay overlay) {
            mOverlay = overlay;
            mFaceGraphic = new FaceGraphic(overlay);
        }

        /**
         * Start tracking the detected face instance within the face overlay.
         */
        @Override
        public void onNewItem(int faceId, Face item) {
            mFaceGraphic.setId(faceId);
        }

        /**
         * Update the position/characteristics of the face within the overlay.
         */
        @Override
        public void onUpdate(FaceDetector.Detections<Face> detectionResults, Face face) {
            mOverlay.add(mFaceGraphic);
            mFaceGraphic.updateFace(face);
            iv.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    iv.setEnabled(true);
                }
            });
        }

        /**
         * Hide the graphic when the corresponding face was not detected.  This can happen for
         * intermediate frames temporarily (e.g., if the face was momentarily blocked from
         * view).
         */
        @Override
        public void onMissing(FaceDetector.Detections<Face> detectionResults) {
            mOverlay.remove(mFaceGraphic);
        }

        /**
         * Called when the face is assumed to be gone for good. Remove the graphic annotation from
         * the overlay.
         */
        @Override
        public void onDone() {
            iv.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    iv.setEnabled(false);
                }
            });
            mOverlay.remove(mFaceGraphic);
        }
    }
```

> How Can I quickly get a callback that face is not in the camera so
>   disable the button. How to remove the delay?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two reasons for the delay in this case: the use of "post" in the code above and the vision API's "maxGapFrames" setting.

The use of "post" in the example above is correct, but this also causes a delay.  The button won't be updated until the UI gets around to executing this queued runnable.  If the app's UI thread is busy doing lots of things, then this might be a while.  One thing that might help would be to decrease the frame rate or preview size of the camera, since this would reduce the rate of work that the device is doing and perhaps make it more responsive:

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/vision/CameraSource.Builder.html#setRequestedFps(float)

For example:

```
mCameraSource = new CameraSource.Builder(context, detector)
    .setRequestedPreviewSize(640, 480)
    .setFacing(CameraSource.CAMERA_FACING_BACK)
    .setRequestedFps(15.0f)
    .build();
```

If you are using either the MultiProcessor or LargestFaceFocingProcessor classes in your app, there is also "maxGapFrames" setting that you may consider adjusting:

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/vision/MultiProcessor.Builder.html#setMaxGapFrames(int)

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/vision/face/LargestFaceFocusingProcessor.Builder.html#setMaxGapFrames(int)

For example, you could set up your MultiProcessor like this:

```
detector.setProcessor(
    new MultiProcessor.Builder<>(new GraphicFaceTrackerFactory())
        .setMaxGapFrames(0)
        .build());
```

By default, this will add a three frame delay between when the face is no longer visible to when "onDone" is called.  Only after the face has been gone for three frames or more will onDone be called.  But you can set this to zero to eliminate this delay.

The purpose of maxGapFrames is to avoid rapidly oscillating between "detected" and "undetected" states, since it is common to encounter intermediate blurred frames from the camera in which the face is not detected (i.e., especially when not holding the camera still enough).  But if that is a non-issue for your app, then setting this to zero should help.

Comment: I am using CameraSourcer.Builder, does that provide frames delay as happening in case of setMaxGapFrames, I think MaxGapFrames is the stuff which is providing immediate callback that face is not in the camera. Am I right??? If yes then how to achieve this using CameraSource.Builder????

Comment: I added some code examples above.  maxGapFrames is not set on the camera source; it is set on the "Processor" instance that runs after face detection is done.  See also this code sample on how the camera source, detector, and processor are put together: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/blob/master/visionSamples/FaceTracker/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/samples/vision/face/facetracker/FaceTrackerActivity.java#L125